# UWP C#. Intercept Copy command in RichEditBox

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, clipboard, richeditbox

I'm developing a UWP app using Xaml and C#. Here is my problem.

My app uses a RichEditBox to process text.  Every time the user close the app the clipboard content copied from within the app is cleared. To solve this issue I red you have to use Clipboard.Flush(). OK, but what happens when I'm not controlling the copy process. If the user press Crtl+C or use the RichEditBox context menu to Copy the text, I can't intercept that action. 
The other workaround is to use Clipboard.ContentChanged. But when I use it for this situation, for some reason, the method creates an infinite loop.
Please, any help.

Comment: What exactly is your question? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Hi @mm8 I'm trying to keep the clipboard content after closing the app. My app uses a RichEditBox. To clarify it better: Create an empty UWP, add a RichEditBox, copy content from it using Ctrl+C and close the app. The content is no longer in the Clipboard. I want to avoid that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Every time the user close the app the clipboard content copied from within the app is cleared.

By testing on my side, if using [`Clipboard.SetContent()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.clipboard.setcontent) method to copy content to clipboard, the content will not be cleared by default after app closed. But if using `Ctrl+C` or right click the context menu, as  you mentioned, the content copy to clipboard will be cleared.

> The other workaround is to use Clipboard.ContentChanged. But when I use it for this situation, for some reason, the method creates an infinite loop

To resolve this, [`Clipboard.ContentChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.clipboard.contentchanged) event handle do help since both  `Ctrl+C` or right click the context menu will trigger this event. The loop is caused by you are trying to  `SetContent` or `Flush` that cause `ContentChanged` trigger again. You could try to remove the event subscription before you are invoking these methods. For example:

```
private async void Clipboard_ContentChanged(object sender, object e)
{
    Clipboard.ContentChanged -= Clipboard_ContentChanged;
    DataPackageView clipboardContent = Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.Clipboard.GetContent();
    var dataPackage = new DataPackage();
    dataPackage.SetText(await clipboardContent.GetTextAsync());
    Clipboard.SetContent(dataPackage);
    Clipboard.ContentChanged += Clipboard_ContentChanged;
   // Clipboard.Flush();
}
```

> Create an empty UWP, add a RichEditBox, copy content from it using Ctrl+C and close the app

Actually, you could re-set the content to clipboard in the app's [suspending event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Application#Windows_UI_Xaml_Application_Suspending) which will be triggered before the app was closed.

```
 private async void OnSuspending(object sender, SuspendingEventArgs e)
 {
     var deferral = e.SuspendingOperation.GetDeferral();
     //TODO: Save application state and stop any background activity 
     DataPackageView clipboardContent = Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.Clipboard.GetContent();
     var dataPackage = new DataPackage();
     dataPackage.SetText(await clipboardContent.GetTextAsync());
     Clipboard.SetContent(dataPackage);          
  // Clipboard.Flush(); 
     deferral.Complete();
 }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is the solution I was looking for. I had "solved" the issue by handling RichEditBox CuttingToClipboard and CopyingToClipboard events but there are available from Fall Creators Update, which means previous versions of the OS will remain with the problem. Thanks a lot for your solution